# Stop-Service giving error in powershell using service account

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code to stop a service using powershell.

I am using a service account which is part of administrator group of the server

```
    $srvName = "K53CMA"
    $servicePrior = Get-Service $srvName
    "$srvName is now " + $servicePrior.status
    
    Stop-Service -Name $srvName -Force
```

But I am getting below error.

```
Stop-Service : Service 'Monitoring Agent for Services - Primary (K53CMA)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open K53CMA service on computer '.'.
```

Please let me know what is the issue here. I have to execute using this service account itself as I have to execute it in different servers

Comment: have you tried with `-Force`?

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli: Yes. it's there in my code.

Comment: are you running this as administrator?

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli: As mentioned, I am using a service account which is a domain admin account

Comment: that's not how windows permissions work. You need to run the prompt as administrator and if it already is, i dont know what the problem could be. Were you able to do it before?

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli: It is part of a task scheduler also. If I do it manually also, from scheduler how I will do that?

Comment: It should depend on how your security options are configured. Are they set to run with the highest privileges?

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli: Yes.

Comment: You can check if the script is running with admin permissions with this long method - outputs true/false: `([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))`. Make sure that `(Get-Service K53CMA | select CanShutdown,CanStop` are true as well